# Remove specific history from SSH command line history

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh

I have accidentally type something in my SSH which now shows my password (obviously I want to remove this)

When I enter the following command I see all my history as follows:

```
$ history
```

History list:

```
997  sudo svn up
998  sudo svn up
999  sudo svn
1000 mypasswordhere
1001 history
```

I simply need to remove the entry from my history that is 1000 mypasswordhere (with mypasswordhere being the password I actually use for some sites so need to remove this)

Can anyone suggest how to remove this single entry (rather than remove everything if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done by executing this command:

```
$ history -d 1000
```

according to documentation accessible when you write `man history`

Comment: perfect - simple yet effective